# Model of nerve viii firing

Tags: neurology, neuroscience, audiology

I'm trying to understand how sound is converted into neural spikes through the auditory system. I've understand that the sound causes the basilar membrane to vibrate in turn causes hair cells to vibrate. The displacement causes ion channels to open or close, hence the membrane potential changes. I've found some models describing the relation between membrane potential and hair cell displacement, and some models saying that the nerve viii firing rate is proportional to the membrane potential of hair cells.

The problem is, are there any models that link the membrane potential of hair cells to the actual firing process of nerve viii? Or we only care the firing rate here, not how the individual spikes are generated?